Common Vulnerabilities and Exposures during docker build
I'm trying to build by project in Docker, So i'm using Docker Desktop to build my project,
when i build the image i get this as one of my vulnerabilities
CVE-2024-26308
CWE-770
7.5
H
Allocation of Resources Without Limits or Throttling vulnerability in Apache Commons Compress. This issue affects Apache Commons Compress: from 1.21 before 1.26. Users are recommended to upgrade to version 1.26, which fixes the issue.
CVSS Score: 7.5
CVSS Vector:    CVSS:3.1/AV:N/AC:L/PR:N/UI:N/S:U/C:N/I:N/A:H
Affected range: >=1.21,<1.26.0
Fix version:    1.26.0
Publish date:   2024-02-19

I would like to fix this, but when i read the bug it say it's due to org.apache.commons, but i don't have it in my dependency, i try running mvn help:effective-pom and  mvn dependency:tree -Dverbose and i still did not find it.
What could be the cause of it and how can i fix it?
Reproduceable code
build the code in docker desktop, and when the image is build, you will see this in the vulnerabilities section.
https://github.com/crazycatMyopic/cve

Is it a vulnerability in the base image? If so it doesn't matter that your code doesn't then depend on it, it still gets reported.

You should define all the plugins which are used during your build like this:
  <build>
    <pluginManagement>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-clean-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.4.0</version>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.4.2</version>
                <dependencies>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
                        <artifactId>commons-compress</artifactId>
                        <version>1.27.0</version>
                    </dependency>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>org.iq80.snappy</groupId>
                        <artifactId>snappy</artifactId>
                        <version>0.5</version>
                    </dependency>
                </dependencies>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-install-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.1.2</version>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-deploy-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.1.2</version>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.3.1</version>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.13.0</version>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.3.1</version>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-failsafe-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.3.1</version>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.7.1</version>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-enforcer-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.5.0</version>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.7.1</version>
                <dependencies>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
                        <artifactId>commons-compress</artifactId>
                        <version>1.27.0</version>
                    </dependency>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>org.iq80.snappy</groupId>
                        <artifactId>snappy</artifactId>
                        <version>0.5</version>
                    </dependency>
                </dependencies>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </pluginManagement>
 </build>

The dependency is used by the maven-jar-plugin and also by the maven-assembly-plugin. The most recent version of maven-jar-plugin uses more recent version but maven-assembly-plugin does not yet do so...so you can define a different version as shown above.

but now it's building jar without a main manifest attribute

In your m2 you have configure the maven-assembly-plugin with the main class... also you have used the <finalName>..</finalName> in the configuration of the maven-assembly-plugin ... that will be the final artifact..

it worked, but i keep getting this cve CVE-2024-36124 relating to this lib org.iq80.snappy, any idea where this might be coming from?

You can add another dependency as mentioned for snappy...updated answer.
